# Location of all mountain peaks of the world

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm looking for something like this page of Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mountains_by_elevation

but with coordinates so that I can load the resulting file in a GIS.

Does somebody now if there is a global mountain peaks database?

Comment: I'd start with geonames.org -- openstreetmap.org may have this also.

Comment: You could iterated all HTMLs on this page via a script and extract the needed data: http://www.peaklist.org/WWlists/ultras/

Comment: The Wikipedia article has a link to wikidata items. Does that Help? https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6629394

Comment: mmm not really. I cannot find any coordinates there to extract

Answer (score 1):

[peaklist.org](http://www.peaklist.org) has a georeferenced dataset of ["ultras"](http://www.peaklist.org/ultras.html) (peaks above 1500 meters in prominence) available as [KMZ](http://peaklist.org/misc/ultrasgoogle052007-linktoKMZ.KMZ).

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yep this is a solution, not exactly what I'm looking for because I need *all* the peaks, also the ones with small prominence.

Answer (score 0):

The [user manual of geonames.org](https://www.geonames.org/manual.html) shows a mountain as one of its examples, so it does seem like their data includes mountains.  It looks like mountains will have the following `data field` values:

- `name`: [mountain name, eg 'Säntis']
- `class`: mountain,hill,rock,...(T)
- `code`: Mountain (MT)

You can download the latest datadump of all geonames data [here](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/allCountries.zip) (this is a direct download link to a 344MB file called allCountries.zip).

Then filter the data to features with `featureCode` = 'MT' and/or `featureClass` = 'T'. Just filtering by feature code will sufficient if the mountain peaks are always categorized as MT, but it depends on how consistent the data is. I wasn't able to open the dataset so I couldn't check on that. If the dataset is really messy you might need to filter it by your list of mountain names, possibly with some fuzzy matching.

It might be advisable to download the data for one country at at time. My GIS program froze when I tried to load the allCountries file. It appears to be in the form of tab-separated values, without a column header line. The latitude and longitude are in fields 6 and 5, respectively. Load it as you would a CSV file, and choose "tab" as the delimiter.

It also looks like you can get this data in the form of a Web Service, but you need to [register](http://www.geonames.org/login) and create a username. So it's free, but not open. [Here's](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html) the documentation about how to write a web service URL query. [Here's](http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html) the list of feature codes. These URLs *should* work if you substitute your username (but I don't have an account so I wasn't able to test them):

XML format: `http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=MT&username=YOURUSERNAME`

JSON format: `http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureCode=MT&username=YOURUSERNAME`

You should be able to load those into a GIS as a Web Feature Service (WFS) layer. Then export it in another format if you want access to the data offline.

OpenStreetMap also has some mountain peaks. You can download them by constructing an HTML query. See the wiki for [documentation about constructing an OSM download query](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6), or use [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/).